# passing data from sqlite to a textview

Tags: java, android, sqlite, textview, parameter-passing

I am trying to pass data from  an sqlite table to a  username textview in my home fragment class, I am having difficulties displaying the data in the textview. 
 Here is my DatabaseHelper class where all my table is created:

public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
// All Static variables
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "u168512214_barzd";

// Login table name
private static final String TABLE_LOGIN = "login";

// Login Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
private static final String KEY_UID = "uid";
private static final String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LOGIN + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT UNIQUE,"
            + KEY_UID + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_CREATED_AT + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE);
}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_LOGIN);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}

/**
 * Storing user details in database
 * */
public void addUser(String name, String email, String uid, String created_at) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, name); // Name
    values.put(KEY_EMAIL, email); // Email
    values.put(KEY_UID, uid); // Email
    values.put(KEY_CREATED_AT, created_at); // Created At

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_LOGIN, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}

/**
 * Getting user data from database
 * */
public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails(){
    HashMap<String,String> user = new HashMap<String,String>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    // Move to first row
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
        Log.i("key_name","value is: " + cursor.getString(1));

         Log.i("key_email","value is: " + cursor.getString(2));
         Log.i("key_uid","value is: " + cursor.getString(3));
         Log.i("key_created_at","value is: " + cursor.getString(4));
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    // return user
    return user;
}


/**
 * Getting user login status
 * return true if rows are there in table
 * */
public int getRowCount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    int rowCount = cursor.getCount();
    db.close();
    cursor.close();

    // return row count
    return rowCount;
}
```

her is my fragmentHome class where I want to display the username in a textView:

DatabaseHandler db;

```
AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();
```

// Session Manager Class
    ArrayList> nameList;

```
public HomeFragment(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
                   btnViewBars = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnViewBars);
          btnNewBar = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnCreateBar);

   // return rootView;
          db= new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());

           HashMap<String, String> user = db.getUserDetails();
           for(int i=0; i<user.size();i++) {

        username.settext(user.get(i).get("name"));

           }
```

Comment: have you checked that there is data being returned from the query? So is your HashMap being populated?

Comment: no I havent because I keep getting this error. my original code (b4 I tried displaying this data) has a login system that uses an online db   and sqlite to log users in. when a user logs in it checks the online database and  and adds the user to the sqlite database too. unless there is data in the sqlite I don't think the user can  log in my  login system was designed based on this tutorial [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/)  if it can help you understand my situation. My final aim is to display the user currently logged in

Comment: I  could display the user logged in using an intent by storing  the user's input in a global variable but . if a user logs in once   he gets automatically logged in the next time so after it will returns null because no data was inputed from the user,I am now trying access the sqlite db to retrieve the user currently signed from there

Comment: just put a `Log.i("key","value is: " + cursor.getString(0));` when you do `cursor.getString(0)` to check what the value is. Also when you get results from a query, the indexing starts at 0 like an array. So instead of `user.put("name", cursor.getString(1));` it would be `user.put("name", cursor.getString(0));`, `user.put("email", cursor.getString(1));` so on and so forth

Comment: it Did return the values now how do I show these values in a texview??

Comment: i think you're iterating the hasmap wrong or something else went wrong and the haspmap isn't being returned. Check the content of your hashmap that was returned from the db. Also where is your `username` declared?